# PlotLabels is not an option for RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, mesh, labeling

```
func={x+y+z<1&&x+y<z,x+y+z<1&&x+z<y,x+y+z<1&&y+z<x,x+y+1<z,x+z+1<y,y+z+1<x};

framelabels = TraditionalForm /@ {Abs[Subscript[u, 1]], 
   Abs[Subscript[u, 2]],Abs[Subscript[u, 3]]};

RegionPlot3D[func,{x,0,2},{y,0,2},{z,0,2},AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},Axes->True,AxesStyle -> Thick,AxesLabel->framelabels,ImageSize->Large,LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Black},Mesh->None,PlotStyle->{Red,Blue,Purple,Brown,Green,Yellow},PlotPoints->100]
```

I used the above code to generate a 3D plot. But I want to add label to different regions in this plot by using `PlotLabels` but it is not working in a 3D plot. Although I used it for 2D `RegionPlot` and it worked well as shown in the diagram below [image].

The exact code for the 2D plot above is:

```
funcs = {x < 1 && y < 1 && x + 2 (x y)^(1/2) < 1, 
    y < 1 && x > 1 && 1/x + 2 (y/x)^(1/2) < 1, 
    ((1/(x y))^(1/2) + (x/( y))^(1/2))^(2) < 4 , 
    x y < 1/4 && y > 1 && x + 2 (x y)^(1/2) < 1, 
   y/ x < 1/4 && y > 1 && 1/x + 2 (y/x)^(1/2) < 1};

labels = TraditionalForm[Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalR], #]]&/@ Range[Length[funcs]];

framelabels = TraditionalForm /@ {Abs[Row[{Subscript[u, 1], "/", Subscript[u, 3]}]], 
   Abs[Subscript[u, 2]]};


RegionPlot[funcs, {x, 0, 9}, {y, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLabels -> Join[Placed[#,Center] & /@ labels[[;;3]],
   {Placed[labels[[4]], {{.1,1.4}, {10,.9}}], Placed[labels[[5]], Center]}], 
 LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> framelabels, 
 RotateLabel -> False, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 12],  
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Cyan, Yellow, Purple}]
```

As you can see the above code I used `PlotLabels` inside `PlotRegion` but when I put it inside `PlotRegion3D` it shows error. So is it not possible for 3D plots in Mathematica or is there any other option specific to the 3D plot?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your question's title to match your question.

[`PlotLabels`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html) is not an option for [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html).

```
Options[RegionPlot3D, PlotLabels]

(* Options::optnf: PlotLabels is not a known option for RegionPlot3D.

{} *)
```

Recommend that you use [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html).

```
func = {x + y + z < 1 && x + y < z, x + y + z < 1 && x + z < y, 
   x + y + z < 1 && y + z < x, x + y + 1 < z, x + z + 1 < y, y + z + 1 < x};

framelabels = 
  TraditionalForm /@ {Abs[Subscript[u, 1]], Abs[Subscript[u, 2]], 
    Abs[Subscript[u, 3]]};

labels = Array[Subscript[ℛ, #] &, Length[func]];
```

The regions' centroids are at

```
pts = RegionCentroid /@ (ImplicitRegion[
       # && 0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 2 && 0 <= z <= 2, {x, y, z}] & /@
     func);
```

Reduce the [`Opacity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) **if** you want to place labels at the centroids.

```
Show[
 RegionPlot3D[func, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesStyle -> Thick,
  AxesLabel -> framelabels,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  LabelStyle -> {14, Bold, Black},
  Mesh -> None,
  PlotStyle -> (Opacity[0.3, #] & /@ {Red, Blue, Purple, Brown, Green, 
      Yellow}),
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotLegends -> labels],
 Graphics3D[
  Text[Style[#[[1]], 18, Bold], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{labels, pts}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I have edited the title. It was my mistake.